# Library Reference Issue using opencv in android

Tags: android, opencv, eye-detection

I am working on opencv face detection project in android. i have an issue regarding Library reference, i have manually set the reference from project properties--->android but it is not been set. kindly help
There is not issue regarding ndk paths or other path settings
screen shot are shown below
[image: this is creen shot where i am setting lib ref but when i clear project, and again this red line with cross sign shows.]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check Android.mk and path to OpenCV Directory.

Please, put Android.mk there and oath to OpenCV lib. And you mast Add OpenCV library to project

Comment: yes! i have done all this and android.mk is also present and paths are cprrectly set. i dnt understand what kind of problem is this

Answer (score 0):

Your library and the project has to be in same directory then it will work..